How to check in jquery if my custom protocol is supported or not
We are using software that registers its own protocol. We can run application from browser then by link like:
customprotocol://do_this.
but is there a way to check is such custom protocol supported by user`s system? If not we would like to ask user to install software first.
if (canHandle ('customprotocol')) {
// run software
}
else {
// ask to install
}

I know this question exists, but it is very old and dates back to 2010
I tried with window.onblur, with a timeout function, but I wasn't successful. I know that iframe doesn't have an error callback, so all options were unsuccessful.

Steam has a custom protocol (steam://), and even it uses two buttons:
Install Steam | Play Now
To test if a URL works, we can use fetch, and if we get a successful response (2XX result), it means the site exists. However, unfortunately, for security reasons, this does not apply to custom protocols.
